# out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/jdwpgen: line 30: dirname: command not found

Tags: android

When I build android from source, normal steps from [android building](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building)

```
make clobber
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm-eng
make -j4
```

errors happen:

```
[ 89% 80075/89120] //external/oj-libjdwp:jdwp_generated_headers 
generate
FAILED: out/soong/.intermediates/external/oj-libjdwp/jdwp_generated_headers/gen/JDWPCommands.h
out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/sbox --sandbox-path out/soong/.temp -- 
output-root out/soong/.intermediates/external/oj- 
libjdwp/jdwp_generated_headers/gen -c 'out/soong/host/linux- 
x86/bin/jdwpgen external/oj-libjdwp/make/data/jdwp/jdwp.spec -include 
__SBOX_OUT_FILES__'  __SBOX_OUT_DIR__/JDWPCommands.h
out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/jdwpgen: line 30: dirname: command not 
found
out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/jdwpgen: line 41: dirname: command not 
found
jdwpgen: can't find jdwpgen.jar
sbox command (out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/jdwpgen external/oj- 
libjdwp/make/data/jdwp/jdwp.spec -include 
out/soong/.temp/sbox176128838/JDWPCommands.h) failed with err "exit 
status 1"

[ 89% 80102/89120] //external/conscrypt:conscrypt-nojarjar javac 
[linux_glibc common]
1 warning
12:12:17 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (01:54:15 (hh:mm:ss)) ####
```

I am sure I have command 'dirname' in my system.

Comment: But can't find 'dirname' command in out directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rerun "repo sync" and rebuilding, it's ok now.